# Organizing images with tabs in rails 4 and bootstrap 3 and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a clients page and I'm using bootstrap tabs to toggle through clients infos and an image gallery. Each client has an image gallery. I am using freewall.js (http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) to organize the images in a responsive grid in which  the images adapt to the empty spaces. The problem is that the only tab that the grid works properly (jquery is applied) is the first one.

My html is:

```
<div class="container" id="client-container">
  <div class="row mb-80 mt-60">
    <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-40 col-sm-3">
        <% @clientes.each do |cliente| %>
          <li>
            <a href="#<%= cliente.id %>", data-toggle="tab", class="tab-links"><%= cliente.name %></a>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <% @clientes.each do |cliente| %>
          <div class="tab-pane fade <%= 'active' if cliente == @clientes.first %>", id="<%= cliente.id %>">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 border col-responsive-xs">
              <div class="description">
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <h1><%= cliente.name %></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left col-lg-9 col-md-11 col-sm-12 mt-40">
                  <p class="lead"><%= cliente.description %></p>
                  <a href="<%= cliente.link %>", target="blank">
                    <p class="lead pull-left">Visite a página da <%= cliente.name %></p>
                  </a>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="image-grid mt-60 freewall" id="freewall">

                <% cliente.cliente_photos.each do |photo| %>
                  <div class="pull-left brick">
                    <a href="<%= photo.imagem.url %>">
                      <%= image_tag photo.imagem.url, class: "img-responsive" %>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                <% end %>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the Jquery is

```
function organizeImages() {
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");   
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 250,
        cellH: 'auto',
        gutterY: 0,
        gutterX: 0,
        onResize: function() {
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    });
    var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
    var length = images.length;
    images.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    images.find('img').load(function() {
        -- length;
        if (!length) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                images.css({visibility: 'visible'});
                wall.fitWidth();
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-links:first').tab('show');
    organizeImages();
    $('.tab-links').on("click", organizeImages());
});
```

I managed to get this far. When the page loads the first tab shows properly with the grid (as I would like). But the other ones don't get the jquery for the grid applied.

Does anyone knows how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can each tab have an instance of Freewall.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".freewall").each(function() {

        var wall = new freewall(this);   
            wall.reset({
                selector: '.brick',
                animate: true,
                cellW: 250,
                cellH: 'auto',
                gutterY: 0,
                gutterX: 0,
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            });
            var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
            var length = images.length;
            images.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
            images.find('img').load(function() {
                -- length;
                if (!length) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        images.css({visibility: 'visible'});
                        wall.fitWidth();
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });


    $('.tab-links:first').tab('show');

    $('.tab-links').on("click", organizeImages());
});
```

And don't set the tabs have display is "none".

Comment: I managed to make the others work. But the styling of the grid only works for the first tab. The other ones are enormous and overflowing the images between themselves, the footer and page width. My jquery looks just like the answer. @MinhNguyen

I forgot to put the project. Maybe this can help.
https://github.com/jppag/Zetta